# Replace specific characters in a string using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, string

I have create an app with black box logic.  I have a configuration and page build based to this.
I use Angular components for all my pages and confirmation pop up message for some actions.

From outside i want to have this structure for confirmation message
like this

```
'Are you sure you want to revoke license for #:SiteName# ?'
```

Inside my components i have a

```
$scope.dataItem = { SiteName: 'stackOverflow', Id: 1}
```

And when from outside i call `showConfirmation('Are you sure you want to revoke license for #:SiteName# ?')`
i want in inside logic to cut and edit this string so the message that i display will be `'Are you sure you want to revoke license for stackOverflow ?'`
or programmaticaly like

```
'Are you sure you want to revoke license for ' + $scope.dataItem.SiteName + ' ?'
```

Basically that i want is to cut this string, edit it and change wherever is

```
#: property # to replace with actually value of $scope.dataItem.property.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```
'Are you sure you want to revoke license for #:SiteName# ?'.replace(/\#\:SiteName\#/, $scope.dataitem.SiteName);
```

**EDIT:**

A bit more reusable code:

```
function replaceSomething(originalString, variableName) {
    var regexPattern = "\#\:" + variableName + "\#";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexPattern, "g");
    return originalString.replace(regex, $scope.dataItem[variableName]);
}
```

Now you use it like:

```
replaceSomething('Are you sure you want to revoke license for #:SiteName# ?', "SiteName");
```

A [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2yt04ztr/33/) of it in action.

A lot of useful information about regular expressions can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

**EDIT2:**

Here is another possibility that might lean closer to what you asked:

```
function replaceSomething(originalString) {
  var regexPattern = "\#\:(.+)\#";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexPattern, "g");
  var variableName = regex.exec(originalString)[1];
  return originalString.replace(regex, $scope.dataItem[variableName]);
}
```

Comment: ok...but i dont want hardcore to have .SiteName, i want to understand 'SiteName' from included #: ... # string

Comment: @GomuGomuNoRocket I updated my answer to include a piece of code that can be reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Well it was easy,

```
args.confirmation.Message = 'Are you sure you want to revoke license for #:SiteName# ?'

var property = args.confirmation.Message.substring(args.confirmation.Message.lastIndexOf("#:") + 2, args.confirmation.Message.lastIndexOf("#"));

var message = args.confirmation.Message.replace('\#\:' + property + '\#', data[property]);
```